# What and how to write unit tests for EF Core configurations through Fluent API?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have a following projects which use Entity Framework Core:

1. `MyApp.Domain`: it contains list of all domain entities mapped to database tables
2. `MyApp.EFConfiguration`: this contains all EF Core related configurations through fluent API.

I am learning to write unit tests cases against each of the above project. Now I think it does not make sense to write unit tests cases against the `MyApp.Domain` project as it contains only the properties and no behaviour to test.

`MyApp.Domain`:

```
public partial class Customer 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Username { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     
     public ICollection<Order> Orders { get;set; }
}

public partial class Order 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }
     
     public decimal CurrencyRate { get; set; }
     public string ShippingMethod { get; set; }

     public Customer Customer { get; set; };
}
```

`MyApp.EFConfiguration`:

```
public class CustomerEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Customer");
            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            builder.Property(c => c.Username).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
            builder.Property(c => c.FirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
            builder.Property(c => c.LastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        }
    }
    
public class OrderEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Orders");
            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            builder.Property(c => c.CustomerId).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(c => c.CurrencyRate).IsRequired();
            
            builder
                .HasOne(order  => order.Customer)
                .WithMany(customer => customer.Orders)
                .HasForeignKey(order => order.CustomerId)
        }
}
```

My first question is does it make sense to write unit tests against all of my configurations like
`CustomerEntityTypeConfiguration`,'`OrderEntityTypeConfiguration`' and others?

If yes then what and how can I unit tests above '`Configure`' method from '`CustomerEntityTypeConfiguration`' and `OrderEntityTypeConfiguration` class?

If someone can help me with unit tests sample for above 2 classes then I can write for others. Any help will be really appreciated. I am using Xunit to write unit tests.

Comment: I think such unit tests are pretty useless. After all, we can set the configuration of entities not only in such classes, but also in the OnConfiguring method and using attributes, as well as using Conventions. Therefore, what this Configure method will output may well be overridden elsewhere. I think there is a point in a more general integration test that checks the structure of the created tables in the database by reading information from the Information schema and comparing it with the desired schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely test your Db configuration so that any changes do not break the expected schema.

In your test project, you can create a new DbContextOptionsBuilder instance and configure an in-memory database. With the options object you can instantiate a DBContext and run any asserts you deem necessary.

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "testDB").Options;
MyContext _context = new MyContextContext(options);
```

Comment: But the question is how and what should I test my Configure method from both the "CustomerEntityTypeConfiguration " and "OrderEntityTypeConfiguration "?

Comment: It's incredible that people still recommend the in-memory database. EF has been discouraging it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would not test `Model` as you said, no behaviour to test, actually you could test that the `Get` and `Set` work, but in that case you would be testing something that is not under your control, but under C# writers control. They are the one that needs to check if their setters work in the way they are expected to work.

I would use the same argument for the `Configuration` class, why should you unit test a class which behaviour is just calling an external library.
Especially if the configuration class is auto generated by EF Core in the case of code first implementations.

On a broader level you could made some test that checks if the database is following a schema you expect, but also in that case I don't think is worth writing that kind of test, because the schema is already documented by your Model, and it is used directly by an external library (ef core).

I don't really see what kind of behaviour you could test in your configuration class, maybe if there was some kind of if inside of it you could test that, but again, because you are calling directly an external library there is any behaviour that you could mess.

Answer (score 0):

**First question:**

> My first question is does it make sense to write unit tests against
> all of my configurations like
> `CustomerEntityTypeConfiguration`,'`OrderEntityTypeConfiguration`' and
> others?

I personally won't write tests for these at db level, because I would make sure that my service validate data before saving to database, so you have some checks in other classes that check for required fields and max lengths. These services would have normal unit tests where you can test these rules

```
//simplified code/logic/flow
public Customer AddNewCustomer (CustomerDto customerDto)
{
    if(customerDto== null)
    {
        //Throw exception or perform other error mechanism
    }

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerDto.FirstName)) 
    {
        //Throw exception or perform other error mechanism
    }

    //other checks
    //save new customer
}
```

and a test:

```
    [Test]
    public void AddCustomer_EmptyFirstName_Throws()
    {
        CustomerDto customerDto = new CustomerDto();
        CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();
        Assert.Throws<CustomerException>(() => customerService.AddNewCustomer(customerDto));
    }
//and other test scenarios for your rules
```

**Second question:**

> If yes then what and how can I unit tests above 'Configure' method
> from 'CustomerEntityTypeConfiguration' and
> OrderEntityTypeConfiguration class?

If you still wanted to do it, you can do the following, but I think this won't work on InMemoryDatabase, you would have to run the test against actual DB:

```
    [Test]
    public void SaveCustomer_LongUserName_Throws()
    {
        using (var context = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var newCustomer = new Customer
            {
                Username =  new string('A', 256),
                FirstName = "first name",
                LastName = "last name",
                Email = "email@somewhere.com"
            };

            context.Customers.Add(newCustomer );

            Assert.That(Assert.Throws<DbUpdateException>(() => context.SaveChanges()).InnerException.Message,
                Is.EqualTo("String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To write unit tests for EF Core configurations through Fluent API:

1. Use an in-memory database.
2. Test each entity configuration separately.
3. Validate database schema and relationships.
4. Check Fluent API configurations with assertions.
5. Ensure tests cover entity creation, relationships, and schema

Comment: It's incredible that people still recommend the in-memory database. EF has been discouraging it all the time.

Comment: @GertArnold Then what is the recommended way to mock Repository which is using EF? Sqllite?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/